# How can I write "OR" with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this piece of code:

```
watches_df = input_csv[input_csv["Name-of-CSV-column"] == "Value-A"].copy()
```

No, I need to rewrite it so instead of selecting only Value-A, I need also to work with the values Value-B and Value-C from this column. I tried different ways how to write it down, but I get the error below.

Basically, I would need something like:

```
watches_df = input_csv[input_csv["Name-of-CSV-column"] == "Value-A" OR "Value-B" OR "Value-C"].copy()
```

but obviously this is wrong as I get this error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1479, in **nonzero** 
> f"The truth value of a {type(self).**name**} is ambiguous.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Pandas-specific question, not Python per se.

You seem to want [`pandas.Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) if your data is in a dataframe:

```
values = {"Value-A", "Value-B", "Value-C"}
watches_df = input_csv[input_csv["Name-of-CSV-column"].isin(values)].copy()
```

With a raw Python list-of-dicts, you'd do something like

```
watches = [watch for watch in watches if watch["column"] in values]
```